# voltage stabilizer current

Tags: lm317, stabilizer

I want to make voltage stabilizer using ic lm317, to power off five white LEDs in series. I need to regulate the current through the diodes in the range of 700mA-1500mA. Have anybody idea how to achive this regulation?

Comment: There is an application within the datasheet showing how to operate the device as a current source.

Comment: *..make voltage stabilizer* ..*regulate the current* So it's a **current source** you're after, not a voltage stabilizer. As Peter suggests, there's an example how to do this in the datasheet of the LM317. At 1.5 A there will be quite a lot of power dissipation in the LM317 so use a heatsink.

Comment: Yeah, but i need to ensure enough voltage to power LEDs too..

Comment: *but i need to ensure enough voltage to power LEDs* Sure but that's still called a current source and the only voltage regulation going on is the LM317 regulating a constant voltage across a resisistor. The current that the LM317 needs to maintain that voltage is also the current through the LEDs. You will have to do some more research in the actual circuit you need and what voltage you need to supply the LM317 + LEDs. It has been done before and we're not going to explain it here so do your research.

Comment: what's your input voltage? Can this even work in theory with a linear regulator?

Comment: I also have doubts why you need / what you mean with *range of 700mA-1500mA*. For dimming that range will not do much, if you want proper dimming you need a range like 15 mA to 1500mA. If you don't need dimming then why regulate over such a wide range? Makes no sense. If the current isn't critical just use a (power) resistor instead of an LM317. Too many unknowns to discuss this properly so voting as unclear.

Comment: This is my project task for school and i can't change components! Input voltage of circuit is not defined, i can use as much as i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard LV317 current regulator circuit on the datasheet is not easy to make adjustable because all of the output current goes through the shunt resistor and that now has to be a pot to be variable.  A pot that can pass 1.5 A is large and expensive.  You can search for 'current regulator circuit' to find many examples of regulator circuits based on a fixed shunt resistor and an opamp.

Comment: The OP didn't say they needed an **adjustable** current, they just specified the desired range of currents. Your suggestion for an internet search doesn't really explain how to overcome the problems you believe will be in the LV317 circuit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a screenshot from the LM317 datasheet
[image]

You can adjust the resistance range value of R1 in order get the desired current by using the below calculation.

I limit = 1.2/R1.

Comment: My concern about this circuit is that (using the equation provided), R1 needs to be a 1 ohm pot (0.8 by calc) rated for at least 2 W (preferably 5 W).